# How to prove the series converges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Show that the series $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty  = \frac{2^j+j}{3^j-j}$ converges.

I know that if I look at each sequential case j=1,2,3... the limit of the partial sums approaches 0 as $j \rightarrow \infty$, but how can I show that the series converges more explicitly?

Comment: Hint: the general term is equivalent (in the very formal sense of Landau notation) to $(2/3)^j$.

Comment: Use the ratio test!

Comment: I tried using the ratio test initially, and ended up with a long fraction along the lines of $|\frac{2(2^n3^n)-2^n(2n)+(n+1)(3^n-n)}{3(2^n3^n)+3^n(3n)+(n+1)(-2^n-n)}|$     and then was not sure where to go from there

Answer (score 1):

Asymptotically, for large $j$, we have

$$\frac{2^j+j}{3^j-j}\sim \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^j$$

Alternatively, we have for $j\ge 1$

$$\frac{2^j+j}{3^j-j}\le\frac{2\times 2^j}{\frac12 3^j}=4 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^j$$

And $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^j=2$.  So, by the comparison test the series of interest converges.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.  - Mark

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\frac{\frac{2^j}{3^j}+\frac{j}{3^j}}{1-\frac{j}{3^j}}$$